# How can the Pandas datetime object be used dynamically?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

Given a dataframe `df` with only one column (consisting of datetime values that can be repeated). e.g:

| date |
| --- |
| 2017-09-17 |
| 2017-09-17 |
| 2017-09-22 |
| 2017-11-04 |
| 2017-11-15 |

and `df.dtypes` is `date      datetime64[ns]`.

How can I create a new dataframe exporting information from the existing one so that for every month of a particular year there will be a second column with the number of observations for that month of the year.

The result for the above example would be something like:

| date | observations |
| --- | --- |
| 2017-09 | 3 |
| 2017-11 | 2 |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do:

```
(df['date'].dt.to_period('M')               # change date to Month
       .value_counts()                      # count the Month
       .reset_index(name='observations')    # make dataframe
)
```

Comment: I never knew that `reset_index()` had a `name` parameter. Is that new?

Comment: @rhug123 I know, there're too many things in Pandas. It's been around since I started using Pandas (0.24 I think).